# Отложенное логирование

Tags: c#, .net, логирование, nlog

Есть приложение, к которому приходит запрос и приложение его обрабатывает. В процессе обработки могут вылезти болячки, которые надо залогировать во время исключения, но вместе с этим необходимо залогировать весь этап обработки (до исключения). Если же запрос отработал без болячек - логировать ничего не требуется.

Итак, сам вопрос в том, есть ли какие-либо уже созданные решения, которые позволили бы хранить промежуточные сообщения во время обработки запроса и логировать их при перехвате исключения и удалять эти промежуточные сообщения при успешной отработке запроса?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66622/discussion-on-question-by-qutrix--).

Answer (score 1):

Готовых обёрток нет.
Реализовать можешь самостоятельно.

Для того, чтобы отловить момент возникновения ошибки, подпишись на событие [`FirstChanceException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception(v=vs.110).aspx).
Для того, чтобы твоё решение нормально работало в многопоточной среде, можешь использовать [`AsyncLocal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx) в качестве хранилища.
Только учитывай, что с таким подходом, тебе нужно жёстко контролировать все возникающие в приложении исключения, и ты не имеешь права их гасить и продолжать операцию в том же контексте.
Чуть более гибкое решение будет заключаться в ручном вызове логирования в блоке `catch`. Таким образом ты сможешь залогировать и полный стек исключения, и отсечь те ошибки, которые логировать не требуется.

Только учти, что отсутствие готовых решений обусловлено, в основном, нежизнеспособностью данного подхода. Когда каждая операция запускается в изолированном домене - это хорошо. Но в многопоточной среде с общими ресурсами, у тебя успешное выполнение одной операции может повлечь отвал другой (хотя бы на одновременном доступе к непотокобезопасной коллекции), и с таким подходом ты потеряешь необходимую информацию и будешь долго гадать - в чём же причина случившегося.

Такой подход может быть оправдан, если ты напишешь собственную виртуальную машину, которая будет, как GC, саспендить все потоки в момент возникновения исключения и делать такой своеобразный мини-дамп состояния по всему приложению, но это больше подойдёт дипломному проекту, нежели принесёт реальную пользу в продакшене.